# Firefox and ydn.db page reload bug

Tags: firefox, ydn-db

ydn.db-isw-core-e-cur-qry-dev-raw.js v1.0.2 crashed at the string 28537

In logs I read:

> AbortError
>   request = index.openKeyCursor(key_range, this.dir);

It crashed in latest Firefox, but works with other browsers.
I  can't find the reason of this error. Sometimes, when I try to debug it by stepping into function,  it works without crashing.

What is causing this bug?

So, when I try to call `history.replaceState()` in callback of `db.put()` it causes a page reload. Why? How can I prevent that?

Comment: Could you file the issue on github?

Answer (score 0):

See debug log by `ydn.debug.log ('ydn.db', 'finest')`

Answer (score 0):

So... I didn't find any reason, but placing history.replaceState() in setTimeout() make it work in FireFox. Maybe there are some problems with context... but it works in other browsers. So, I think that it is very strange bug of firefox.